# Calculate date using PHP

Tags: php, date

I am currently using the following PHP string which collects the due date from an invoice in the format DD.MM.YYYY.

```
<?php echo date_from_mysql($invoice->invoice_date_due , TRUE); ?>
```

I would like to automatically calculate the date five days prior to this, and if possible, have it display in full (eg. Monday, 1st January 2016)

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime)

Comment: read the PHP manual for the multitude of date and time related functions. You can even google your question and various correct answers will magically appear.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) for this, and the [`sub()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) function.

```
$objDate = new \DateTime(date_from_mysql($invoice->invoice_date_due , TRUE), new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$objDate->sub(new DateInterval('P5D')); //minus 5 days
echo $objDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

https://eval.in/512035

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your required date formation

```
<?php
 $date = new DateTime('01.02.2016');  //modify if you wish
 $date->sub(new DateInterval('P5D')); //calculate the date five days prior 
 echo $date->format('l, jS F Y') . "\n"; //formatted as you mentioned
?>
```